My professor wanted me to use eBPF to find how the 802.11x WiFI headers are added on the device from the system what should I do here?
I reconfigured the kernel and made the enviroment ready, now how can I trace a certain source code function from a certain subset mac80211x?
Lets say I want to trace a function puts_wifi_header which is defined inside mac80211x. This is a souce file for the kernel. Can I trace what happens in this function?

I don't get it. If the goal is to understand how something is implemented in the kernel or its drivers, why not just read the source code? How would eBPF help?

Are you looking for kprobes? https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/kprobes.html . If yes, then maybe looking at BCC examples help you.  https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/examples/tracing/tcpv4connect.py
